# Re - installing Windows 8 on a tablet, without usb-boot option

Tags: windows-8, boot, tablet, windows-tabletpc

I do own a tablet (**Xoro PAD 9W4**), which initially ran Windows 8.1. I upgraded to Windows 10, but due to some issues (mainly touchscreen issues), I want to reinstall Windows 8.1. For this reason, I made a bootable USB flash drive.

Although I managed to enter UEFI BIOS, there is no option in `boot manager` to boot from usb. In particular the displayed message is: `System doesn't have any USB boot option`. Is there anything I can do about it?

P.S. Unfortunately, there is no official support for the specific model.

Comment: It would be helpful to know specifically what model of tablet you're dealing with.

Comment: Try a refresh ==> http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2293-refresh-windows-8-a.html

Comment: @whs I'm afraid there is no such an option. Instead, the only options are`Reset this Pc` and `advanced settings`, which I tried both without any result. By the way, the running OS at the moment is Windows 10.

Comment: [See this page](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/how-downgrade-windows-10-to-windows-7-8-3615606/)

Comment: I understand that you are currently running Windows 10. But the W10 installation should not have erased the W8.1 recovery partitions. Thus a recovery to W8.1 should be possible. Maybe this will work ==> http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2302-reset-windows-8-a.html